# How to query where from dictionary column with datatype string in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a column where it contains dictionary that has a data type string.  How do I query where attributes.statusSource = source in bigquery sql?
Here is an example

| id | attributes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"flushOut": 0, "expiration": 0, "productAge": 0, "sourceStatus": "SOURCE", "criticalStatus": false, "storageHandling": "FROZEN", "expirationReminder": 0} |
| 2 | {"flushOut": 0, "expiration": 0, "productAge": 0, "sourceStatus": "DISCONTINUE", "criticalStatus": false, "storageHandling": "FROZEN", "expirationReminder": 0} |

what I want returned is where attribute.sourceStatus = "source"

| id | attributes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"flushOut": 0, "expiration": 0, "productAge": 0, "sourceStatus": "SOURCE", "criticalStatus": false, "storageHandling": "FROZEN", "expirationReminder": 0} |

Comment: What is the data type of `attributes`? Is it STRING or JSON?

Comment: yes, thank you for reminding to check the data type. it's string. how do I handle string do I cast it as json or do I do a regex for values? However there's the " " that needs to be handled

Comment: Currently, JSON functionality is in preview and to use that you have to fill the form. For now, I would recommend using [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) to extract the parameter value from JSON string and then using the extracted value for comparison.

Comment: Don't the standard functions work? e.g. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value

Comment: nope the standard function didn't work, the answer below json_extract_scalar does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR()` :

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT '{"flushOut": 0, "expiration": 0, "productAge": 0, "sourceStatus": "SOURCE", "criticalStatus": false, "storageHandling": "FROZEN", "expirationReminder": 0}' as attributes
UNION ALL
SELECT '{"flushOut": 0, "expiration": 0, "productAge": 0, "sourceStatus": "DISCONTINUE", "criticalStatus": false, "storageHandling": "FROZEN", "expirationReminder": 0}' as attributes
) WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(attributes, '$.sourceStatus') = 'SOURCE'
```